# Not yet able to install sagemath-upstream-binary from ppa. Should I just be a little more patient and try again latter?

Tags: ppa, sagemath

At this time (2014, October the 27th) I am not able to install `sagemath-upstream-binary` in my recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 utopic from ppa:aims/sagemath. I strongly suspect that I just need to wait a couple of more weeks or so for the ppa:aims/sagemath site to get updated.

I recently upgraded my OS to 14.10. In previous versions of Ubuntu I have been able to install `sagemath` by using the methods suggested by https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath. So far after I run the commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:aims/sagemath
sudo apt-get update
```

I end up with the following warning in the update

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Which in turn explains why when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

I get the following error of

```
E: Unable to locate package sagemath-upstream-binary
```

Do I just need to be patient and hope that ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages will soon be added, or should I just learn how to build the program from the source code?

Comment: Any progress on this question? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I think that there were various other questions on this at the time; check again now, it should be okay.

Comment: This is a stupid effect of frequent changes of releases.  I got into this same problem with 17.04 now...

Comment: @V-X I have this problem on 17.04 as well.